# Getting garbage when reading string from std::smatch

Tags: c++, regex, string, memory, cout

I'm trying to fix a memory issue, I think, for several hours now and I can't understand the issue of the problem.

I have a classes `StaticTag` and `ExtendsTag` that I create with result of `std::smatch` (`<regex>`). Method creating `StaticTag` always works, but method creating `ExtendsTag` never works. The only difference is regular expression which works all the time because the substring is matched. Problem here is even printing a captured group which mostly all the time gives me a garbage with suffix of correct string. Here is the code.

Execution of two methods `find_static_tag` and `find_extends_tag` (the latter does not work):

```
StaticTag static_tag;
if (Regex::find_static_tag(this->_content, static_tag)) {

}

ExtendsTag extends_tag;
if (Regex::find_extends_tag(this->_content, extends_tag)) {

}
```

Both methods presented below:

```
bool Regex::find_extends_tag(std::string in, ExtendsTag& tag) {
    std::string pattern = "\\{%\\s*extends\\s+\"(\\S+)\"\\s*%\\}";
    std::smatch match;
    if (Regex::find_first(pattern, in, match)) {
        std::cout << match[1] << std::endl;
        tag = ExtendsTag(match[1], match.position(), match.length());
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

bool Regex::find_static_tag(std::string in, StaticTag& tag) {
    std::string pattern = "\\{%\\s*static\\s+\"(\\S+)\"\\s*%\\}";
    std::smatch match;
    if (Regex::find_first(pattern, in, match)) {
        std::cout << match[1] << std::endl;
        tag = StaticTag(match[1], match.position(), match.length());
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

They need to match: `{% static "style.css" %}` and `{% extends "master.html" %}`.

Usually I got something like this instead of "master.html": �0e.html.

I think it might be memory issue, but I don't know where to start because two methods looks identical for me. It is not about creating objects of `StaticTag` and `ExtendsTag`, it fails printing `match[1]` in `find_extends_tag` method.

**EDIT**: Look like when I change from `static` to `extends` in the second method the result is the same. Is this something wrong with `<regex>` then?

Thank you for your help in advance!

The file I am trying to parse:

```
{% extends "master.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <p>Hello ios/index.html</p>
    <img src="{% static "html-css.png" %}"/>
{% endblock %}
```

**EDIT 2:**
Not sure why it started to work. I took out implementation of `Regex::find_first(pattern, in, match)` and put it directly in `find_static_tag` and `find_extends_tag` and it started to work correctly.

Here is implementation of `find_extends_tag` that works always:

```
bool Regex::find_extends_tag(std::string in, ExtendsTag& tag) {
    std::smatch match;
    if (std::regex_search(in, match, std::regex("\\{%\\s*extends\\s+\"(\\S+)\"\\s*%\\}"))) {
        tag = ExtendsTag(match[1], match.position(), match.length());
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Not sure what's the difference here.

Comment: Why can't these be combined into a singular regular expression of the form `(?:static|extends)`? It seems like what you really need is a parser but a regular expression could be one way of bootstrapping this.

Comment: @tadman, on this specific case yes, they could, but I want to create different objects for different regular expressions with different number of params - so at the moment wanted to keep them separated.

Comment: At some point a regular expression will no longer cut it and what you need is a simple tokenizing parser. These aren't that hard to implement and offer significantly more flexibility than a regular expression.

Comment: @tadman will read about tokenizing parser, thanks for advice!